# Marketing Cloud Mobile Events

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk

I would like to ask about the app events that SFMC SDK sends to SFMC.
It is possible to see the devices who installed the app but is it possible to know whether the app is uninstalled?
Which events are being sent to the SFMC by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither platform notifies the software layer when an application is uninstalled.  There is no way for the SDKs to detect this.

Comment: Thanks but how can we explain that SFMC tracks the opt-out flag when the app is uninstalled?

Comment: It doesn't do so directly.  We are 100% dependent on Apple/Google notifying us that a device is no longer valid.